# how to use Bingmaps in windowsphone7 with visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to use a bing maps control on a windows phone 7 silverlight application and I've tried follow from this sites: http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2009/12/30/day-30-bing-maps-in-silverlight/
  But it shows this error:

> The tag 'Map' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl'.

am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have added `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps` assembly to the project references.

In your PhoneApplicationPage add the following attribute:

```xaml
xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps"
```

And to use the Map control in your page do as following:

```xaml
<maps:Map />
```

Comment: successful.thank you very much.